# How do I implement Hash for Cell<MyType> in order to put it into a set?

Tags: rust, hashset

As my first Rust project, I'm working on a simple graph library. I want my graph root to have a reference to all nodes doing memory management by reference counting, but the following doesn't compile:

```
pub struct Graph {
    nodes: HashSet<Rc<Cell<Node>>>
}

impl Hash for Cell<Node> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        let pointer = &self as *const isize;
        pointer.hash(state);
    }
}

pub struct Relationship {
    source: Rc<Cell<Node>>,
    target: Rc<Cell<Node>>,
}
pub struct Node {
    labels: Vec<Rc<String>>,
    attributes: Vec<Rc<String>>,
    relationships: Vec<Rc<Relationship>>
}
```

with the following error:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented 
for arbitrary types
  --> src\graph/mod.rs:12:1
   |
12 |   impl Hash for Cell<Node> {
   |  _^ starting here...
13 | |     fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
14 | |        
15 | |     }
16 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here: impl doesn't use types inside crate
   |
   = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, because in this case the generic parameter implemenation of the trait is owned by the user

Comment: Please read again the [rules for implementing traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#rules-for-implementing-traits). Both `Cell` and `Hash` are part of the standard library, so you cannot implement one for the other.

Comment: ok, i thought by binding the generic parameter to a type of my ownership (Node) would also give me the ownership of the combination (Cell<Node>), which is not the case, right?

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't.